# Decorate words with type using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to decorate the words using CSS only to get this result? I need to underline them with different colors, and add the type as text (in CSS).

[image]

Ideally, the HTML content should not be touched but I could do minor changes to it:

```
<p>
  <span class="xart">The</span>
  <span class="xadj">big</span>
  <span class="xn">house</span>.
</p>
```

What should I add to the CSS styles?

```
.xart { text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: blue; }
.xadj { text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: green }
.xn { text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: bred; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791793/css-multiple-text-decorations-with-style-and-color
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840403/edit-line-thickness-of-css-underline-attribute

Comment: It is not convenient to hack CSS to add letters, but some combo with spans, content and position as mentioned in the link above can be used

Comment: Right, but how to I add the words "adj", "art", "n" below the main words using CSS? I guess Javascript is an option too.

Comment: Will try using "content", then. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smollet92/94bwdz6e/ here is solution using pseudo-elements

Comment: @Smollet777 Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying [CSS - Multiple text-decorations with style and color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791793/css-multiple-text-decorations-with-style-and-color)

```css
span {
    position: relative;
}
span.art:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    content: 'art'; 
    color:blue;
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    top: 20px;
}
span.adj:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    content: 'adj'; 
    color:green;
    border-top: 2px solid green;
    top: 20px;
    left: 2px
}
span.n:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    content: 'n'; 
    color:red;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    top: 20px;
    left: 2px
}
```

```html
<span class="under art">The</span> <span class="under adj">big</span> <span class="under n">house</span>
```

Comment: I used `text-align: center` in my example and tried in yours. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the styles you are looking for in the following way.

```css
.xart {
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.xart:after {
 content: 'art';
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.xadj {
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.xadj:after {
 content: 'adj';
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid green;
}

.xn {
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.xn:after {
 content: 'n';
 display: block;
 border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="xart">The</span>
  <span class="xadj">big</span>
  <span class="xn">house</span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I add the words "adj", "art", and "n" below the main words?

Comment: Do those words need to be added via CSS? Also, is a javascript solution acceptable?

Comment: Ideally CSS, but that's thinking outside the box. Thanks for the Javascript idea!

Comment: @TheImpaler, you can add the words in using pseudo elements (`::before`) with `content: 'the text';` and just absolutely position them within each span to be below (make sure you make the spans `position: relative;` to contain it)

Comment: @TheImpaler I have come up with a CSS only solution. Please see my updated snippet.

Comment: @DeDee Mine looks better